# Get Value for Field Name in SharePoint 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

**What do I want to archive:**

I am trying to select several values out of a TaskList in SharePoint 2013 via a Timer Job. I am trying to get the `% completed` value to determine in which completetion state the current task is.

**What do I have done until now:**

I have following Code which is used as soon as the Job is executed:

```
public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
{
    SPWebApplication webApp = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;
    SPSite siteCollection = webApp.Sites[5];
    SPListCollection taskListCollection = webApp.Sites[5].RootWeb.Lists;
    SPList taskList = taskListCollection.TryGetList("TestCustomTasks");
    SPListItemCollection Items = taskList.Items;
    foreach (SPListItem item in Items)
    {
        SPField xyz = item.Fields.TryGetFieldByStaticName("% Complete");
    }
}
```

**My Issue:**

Everything works well until the `SPField xyz ...` but the variable `xyz` is null. He doesn't seem to know this column. But it is there:

[image]

Is it because of a missspelling in the function call or do I miss anything?

Comment: I believe the internal name of the "% Complete" field on an out-of-the-box task list is `PercentComplete`. Have you tried using that instead of "% Complete"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it this way:

```
foreach (SPListItem item in Items)
{
    bool assadfsdasdad = item["PercentComplete"].ToString().Equals("1");
}
```

`.ToString().Equals("1")` is just for quick checking if the Value is in an expected state.

Thanks anyway for all your suggestions and answers ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 SPField xyz = item.Fields.TryGetFieldByStaticName("PercentComplete");
```

Comment: but with this I am not getting the current value of the list item for this field. I get the Field but that is not what I want to archive (see question)

Comment: your suggestion is for the Field only but not the value of this Field... See my answer for my solution.